# Generating different sizes of Images

Tags: css, facebook, image-scaling

Does anyone know how Facebook, Pinterest and Twitter keep different sizes of images of a given image. Facebook, for example, scales a given image to 4 different sizes and stores them. Pinterest keeps two sizes of images (one is 236px and the other is 736px); tumblr does the same with different values. I am trying to do the same thing but i do not get correct results. In python, using the Image library (from PIL), if i use resize, image gets stretched, if i used thumbnails, i get images based on aspect ratio rather than the dimensions i want (e.g. 300px by 300px).

If you look at one's Facebook profile picture, it is scaled from 520px by 520px to 160px by 160px, but there was no cropping done to achieve that. If anyone has an idea of how can this be achieved, I would really like to know

Answer (score -1):

I guess this may help you <kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/gLmXx/)</kbd>

HTML

```
<section>
    <form>
        <div class="options">
            <label for="width">Width:</label>
            <input id="width" type="number" name="width" value="100">
            <label for="height">Height:</label>
            <input id="height" type="number" name="height" value="100">
            <input type="checkbox" id="crop">
            <label for="crop">crop thumbnail</label> <span class="crop"><label for="bg">background:</label><input type="text" value="white" id="bg"></span>

            <input type="checkbox" id="jpeg">
            <label for="jpeg">JPG</label> <span class="jpeg"><label for="quality">Quality</label>
    <input type="number" max="100" min="0" value="50" id="quality"> %</span>

        </div>
        <div id="dropzone">This demo needs a canvas and FileReader capable browser</div>
    </form>
    <output>
         <h2>Thumbnails (click to remove, hover to see filesize)</h2>

    </output>
</section>
```

js

```
/*
  canvasthumber by Christian Heilmann
  Version: 1.0
  Homepage: http://thewebrocks/demos/canvasthumber
  Copyright (c) 2012, Christian Heilmann
  Code licensed under the BSD License:
  http://wait-till-i.com/license.txt
*/
(function () {
    var s = document.querySelector('#dropzone'),
        o = document.querySelector('output'),
        cr = document.querySelector('#crop'),
        j = document.querySelector('#jpeg'),
        c = document.createElement('canvas'),
        cx = c.getContext('2d'),
        thumbwidth = thumbheight = 100,
        crop = false,
        background = 'white',
        jpeg = false,
        quality = 0.8;

    function init() {
        if (typeof FileReader !== 'undefined') {
            document.body.classList.add('dragdrop');
            s.innerHTML = 'Drop images here';
            cr.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
                document.body.classList.toggle('cropon');
            }, false);
            j.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
                document.body.classList.toggle('jpegon');
            }, false);
            o.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
                var t = evt.target;
                if (t.tagName === 'IMG') {
                    t.parentNode.removeChild(t);
                }
            }, false);
            s.addEventListener('dragover', function (evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();
            }, false);
            s.addEventListener('drop', getfiles, false);
        }
    };

    function getfiles(ev) {
        var files = ev.dataTransfer.files,
            url = window.URL || window.webkitURL,
            objURL = url.createObjectURL || false;

        if (files.length > 0) {
            var i = files.length;
            while (i--) {
                var file = files[i];
                if (file.type.indexOf('image') === -1) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (objURL) {
                    loadImage(url.createObjectURL(file));
                } else {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                    reader.onload = function (ev) {
                        loadImage(ev.target.result);
                    };
                }
            }
        }
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function loadImage(file) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = file;
        img.onload = function () {
            grabformvalues();
            imagetocanvas(this, thumbwidth, thumbheight, crop, background);
        };
    }

    function grabformvalues() {
        thumbwidth = document.querySelector('#width').value;
        thumbheight = document.querySelector('#height').value;
        crop = document.querySelector('#crop').checked;
        background = document.querySelector('#bg').value;
        jpeg = document.querySelector('#jpeg').checked,
        quality = document.querySelector('#quality ').value / 100;
    }

    function imagetocanvas(img, thumbwidth, thumbheight, crop, background) {
        c.width = thumbwidth;
        c.height = thumbheight;
        var dimensions = resize(img.width, img.height, thumbwidth, thumbheight);
        if (crop) {
            c.width = dimensions.w;
            c.height = dimensions.h;
            dimensions.x = 0;
            dimensions.y = 0;
        }
        if (background !== 'transparent') {
            cx.fillStyle = background;
            cx.fillRect(0, 0, thumbwidth, thumbheight);
        }
        cx.drawImage(
        img, dimensions.x, dimensions.y, dimensions.w, dimensions.h);
        addtothumbslist(jpeg, quality);
    };

    function addtothumbslist(jpeg, quality) {
        var thumb = new Image(),
            url = jpeg ? c.toDataURL('image/jpeg', quality) : c.toDataURL();
        thumb.src = url;
        thumb.title = Math.round(url.length / 1000 * 100) / 100 + ' KB';
        o.appendChild(thumb);
    };

    function resize(imagewidth, imageheight, thumbwidth, thumbheight) {
        var w = 0,
            h = 0,
            x = 0,
            y = 0,
            widthratio = imagewidth / thumbwidth,
            heightratio = imageheight / thumbheight,
            maxratio = Math.max(widthratio, heightratio);
        if (maxratio > 1) {
            w = imagewidth / maxratio;
            h = imageheight / maxratio;
        } else {
            w = imagewidth;
            h = imageheight;
        }
        x = (thumbwidth - w) / 2;
        y = (thumbheight - h) / 2;
        return {
            w: w,
            h: h,
            x: x,
            y: y
        };
    };
    init();
})();
```

css

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 2em;
}
footer, section, output, header, aside, figure {
    display: block;
}
a {
    color: #060;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 24px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.dragdrop #dropzone {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px dotted #393;
    background: #cfc;
    color: #393;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.dragdrop output {
    width: 520px;
    display: block;
    float: left
}
output img {
    margin: 5px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
footer {
    clear:both;
}
section, header, footer {
    width: 800px;
}
input[type=number] {
    width: 3em;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
    margin-right: 10px
}
label {
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#bg {
    width: 5em;
}
.jpeg {
    opacity: 0.2;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    -moz-transition: 1s;
    -ms-transition: 1s;
    -o-transition: 1s;
    transition: 1s;
}
.crop {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    -moz-transition: 1s;
    -ms-transition: 1s;
    -o-transition: 1s;
    transition: 1s;
}
.cropon .crop {
    opacity: 0.2;
}
.jpegon .jpeg {
    opacity: 1;
}
.options {
    background: #060;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #333;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}
output img {
    display:block;
}
output img:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #ccc;
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 12px;
}
footer {
    clear: both;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 50px 0 20px 0;
    font-size: 12px;
}
footer a {
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: wow....ill have a look at the code in more detail...but im assuming this wont work with HTML emails, right? if not, u think a better way would be to generate images of different sizes using ur code on my computer/server and use them in my html emails???

Comment: You can always do that with css like  img {
    display: block;
    max-width:/* max-width you want */;
    max-height:/* max-height you want */;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

; here I just gave a dynamic solution with javascript.

Comment: This answer simply provides snippets of code with no clear explanations of what we're trying to achieve.